# I didn't know what was wrong, no error message, no running, no debug....(wxpython)

Tags: eclipse, wxpython

I made a calculator (to enter number ourselves, not using buttons) with eclipse. I designed it like this.

[image]

Explanation of the picture:

1. enter the numbers using the keyboard
2. choose the arithmetic process
3. The result comes out

but it didn't run (shut down the window), didn't debug..... with no error message.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(400,200))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        calcus = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(calcus)

        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)


        button5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(button5)
        eq = wx.Button(self, label=u"=") 
        button5.Add(eq, 1, wx.GROW)

        self.text3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)


        def Click1(event):
            value1 = self.text1.GetValue() 
            value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
            value3 = value1 + value2 
            self.text3.SetValue(self,value3)

        def Click2(event):
            value1 = self.text1.GetValue() 
            value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
            value3 = value1 - value2 
            self.text3.SetValue(self,value3)

        def Click3(event):
            value1 = self.text1.GetValue() 
            value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
            value3 =  value1 * value2
            self.text3.SetValue(self,value3)

        def Click4(event):
            value1 = self.text1.GetValue() 
            value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
            value3 =  value1 / value2
            self.text3.SetValue(self,value3)

            buttons = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.SetSizer(buttons)
            plu = wx.Button(self, label=u"+") 
            miu = wx.Button(self, label=u"-") 
            mut = wx.Button(self, label=u"x") 
            did = wx.Button(self, label=u"%") 

            plu.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Click1)
            miu.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Click2)
            mut.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Click3)
            did.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Click4)

            buttons.Add(plu, 1, wx.GROW)
            buttons.Add(miu, 1, wx.GROW)
            buttons.Add(mut, 1, wx.GROW)
            buttons.Add(did, 1, wx.GROW)

            calcus.Add(self.text1, 4, wx.GROW)
            calcus.Add(buttons, 1, wx.GROW)
            calcus.Add(self.text2, 4, wx.GROW)
            calcus.Add(button5, 1, wx.GROW)
            calcus.Add(self.text3, 4, wx.GROW)

            self.Center()
            self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Calculator")
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your code.

The window size is not being set wide enough to show all controls.

A lot of the widget creation code is indented inside of the click4 event handler.

setsizer only needs to be used once.

Event handlers indention is wrong.

Event handlers should have self as first parameter.

The text controls getvalue method returns a string which needs to be converted into a number and then back to a string after calculations.

All the event handlers are doing multiplication only.

The following code works but could be improved more by removing duplicated code ect

```
import wx


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(600, 200))

#         sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
#         self.SetSizer(sizer)

        calcus = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(calcus)

        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        button5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
#         self.SetSizer(button5)
        eq = wx.Button(self, label=u"=")
        button5.Add(eq, 1, wx.GROW)

        self.text3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        buttons = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
#         self.SetSizer(buttons)
        plu = wx.Button(self, label=u"+")
        miu = wx.Button(self, label=u"-")
        mut = wx.Button(self, label=u"x")
        did = wx.Button(self, label=u"%")

        plu.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click1)
        miu.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click2)
        mut.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click3)
        did.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click4)

        buttons.Add(plu, 1, wx.GROW)
        buttons.Add(miu, 1, wx.GROW)
        buttons.Add(mut, 1, wx.GROW)
        buttons.Add(did, 1, wx.GROW)

        calcus.Add(self.text1, 4, wx.GROW)
        calcus.Add(buttons, 1, wx.GROW)
        calcus.Add(self.text2, 4, wx.GROW)
        calcus.Add(button5, 1, wx.GROW)
        calcus.Add(self.text3, 4, wx.GROW)

        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def click1(self, event):
        value1 = self.text1.GetValue()
        value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
        value3 = float(value1) + float(value2)
        self.text3.SetValue('{}'.format(value3))

    def click2(self, event):
        value1 = self.text1.GetValue()
        value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
        value3 = float(value1) - float(value2)
        self.text3.SetValue('{}'.format(value3))

    def click3(self, event):
        value1 = self.text1.GetValue()
        value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
        value3 = float(value1) * float(value2)
        self.text3.SetValue('{}'.format(value3))

    def click4(self, event):
        value1 = self.text1.GetValue()
        value2 = self.text2.GetValue()
        value3 = float(value1) / float(value2)
        self.text3.SetValue('{}'.format(value3))


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Calculator")
app.MainLoop()
```